# OpenWrt DHCPv6 relay bad results for ping

Tags: ipv6, openwrt

Device: NETGEAR wndr3700v4

OpenWrt Ver: 15.05 Chaos Calmer

After setting up DHCPv6 relay with instructions in [Wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network6), I can get IPv6 address on my laptop and `dig` can return IPv6 DNS.

`ping6 ipv6.google.com` also seems good when I sshed into router.

But when I tried to `ping6 ipv6.google.com` on mac, all I can get is

`PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2402:f000:5:7001:5dc7:5d1c:3f50:2c41 --> 2404:6800:4005:801::200e
^C
--- ipv6.l.google.com ping6 statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the `v6brouter` script I wrote to address this kind of problem. It used `ebtables` to bridge IPv6 while still routing IPv4:

https://github.com/cvmiller/v6brouter